# Use AVFoundation to selecte image from photo album

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios6, avfoundation

Is it possible to implement with `AVFoundation` :

picking an image from photo album similar to `UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not AVFoundation, but you can use [AssetsLibrary](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/AssetsLibraryFramework/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009730). From the UIImagePickerViewController documentation:

> To create a fully-customized image picker for browsing the photo library, use classes from the Assets Library framework. For example, you could create a custom image picker that displays larger thumbnail images, that makes use of EXIF metadata including timestamp and location information, or that integrates with other frameworks such as Map Kit. For more information, see Assets Library Framework Reference. Media browsing using the Assets Library framework is available starting in iOS 4.0

Any image available to the Photos app can be accessed using `ALAssetsLibrary` class. Note that you will have your work cut out for you; you'll have to create the UI for picking images from the Photo Library from scratch.

Reference is [available here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/AssetsLibraryFramework/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009730)